# Auto-Logon without registry hack in Windows 7 with Domain Account

Tags: windows-7, autologon

i'm having a bit of an issue/task and need to find out if there's a solution.

GOAL: We want a desktop computer to "autologon" with a Domain User Account in Windows 7

CHALLENGES:
Due to our security policies, the password should not be viewable in cleartext (if possible) and we definitely can't use the registry hack that most people use due to internal security restrictions.
Also the flag "users need to enter the password" can't be taken away as it's not visible on our image (probably because it was removed due to security restrictions)

Any idea?

Comment: Your security restrictions rule out the only solution...

Comment: If security is that tight, you should really be working with the system admins to attempt this. Questions about corporate networks are off topic.

Comment: You have ruled out all possible solutions due to your security.  I would talk to your IT department about possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: This sounds like Hell's IT manager ...

Answer (score 0):

You can auto login using a third party program called [logon.exe](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/51.htm)

It should do what you want.

You'll need to create a scheduled task to automatically start the logon.exe and you will be storing the password in the scheduled task. You also need to set the login method to classic for this to work.

If you make sure the user does not have administrative rights, and as such cannot access the task scheduler, they should in theory not be able to see the task and thus not be able read the password.